# How to set ANT path in Windows 10?

Tags: ant, windows-10

I am not able to set ANT path in Windows 10.

**Right click of PC-->Properties-->Advance system setting-->Advance-->Env** variable. Clicked on new on variable

**Variable name:** ANT_HOME
**Variable value:** C:\Windows\apache-ant-1.10.

Clicked on system variable name set the 
**path**  C:\Windows\apache-ant-1.10.1\bin
checked in cmd prompt using ANT

I am getting ANT is not recognized as an internal or external command. I tried with system variable and system path too and in the env path too I have provided path till bin i.e **C:\Windows\apache-ant-1.10.1\bin**
still not able to install it.

Comment: You must add the bon/ directory to the PATH environment variable so that Wibndows can locate the ant.bat or ant.cmd command

Comment: Your ANT_HOME has `apache-ant-1.10`, but the PATH has `apache-ant-1.10.1` (notice the extra "**.1**"). Which one should it be?